# super() behaviour in java when calling parent constructor explicitly

Tags: java, multithreading, super

```
class NewThread1 extends Thread{

    NewThread1(String name){

    super(name); //this line replaced by 'new Thread(name);'

    System.out.println("child Thread:"+this);

    }
}

public class ThreadCreationExtend {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewThread1("Thread1");
        new NewThread1("Thread2");
    }
}

output:child Thread:Thread[Thread1,5,main]
       child Thread:Thread[Thread2,5,main]

output after replacement: 
                          child Thread:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
                          child Thread:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
```

I'm trying to call the Thread class constructor, Thread(String name) instead of using super(name) but when i use new Thread(String name) output is coming different. Please explain the different output.
Is it because of the default super constructor? If so then how do i use the parent constructor Thread(String name) without super()?

Comment: `new Thread(name)` just creates a new thread object. Using super(...) to call parent constructor is the only way to do it in java (you don't have multiple inheritance so there is no problem with it).

Comment: As a general note, it's usually bad practice to create your own thread classes. Use `Runnable`, and even then it's usually better to run them on an executor instead of individual threads.

Comment: @chrylis can you explain what do you mean by executer?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`super(name)` and `new Thread(name);` do not, remotely, do the same thing.

`super(name)` calls the parent constructor for the current instance, giving it its chance to initialize its part of the instance before the subclass starts the process of initializing *its* parts of the instance.

`new Thread(name)` creates an entirely separate, new `Thread`, and then throws it away (as you never save the result anywhere). It's exactly like any other time you use `new`: You're creating a **new** object, not calling your superclass constructor.

> If so then how do i use the parent constructor Thread(String name) without super()?

Your subclass needs to give the superclass a chance to do its initialization. If you don't code a call to `super(...)`, the Java compiler will insert a call to `super()` (no parameters) for you. So the question doesn't really make sense: In a `Thread` subclass, you give the `Thread` its chance to initialize by using `super(...)`. You do not use `new Thread(...)` for that.

You *can* use `new Thread` in that code to create an entirely new, separate, independent thread, just like you can use `new HashMap` to create a new `HashMap`. But I very much doubt you want to. It would have nothing to do with the fact your class's superclass is `Thread`.

Comment: But why doesn't the superclass constructor is called when i write new Thread(name)? It should call Thread(name). Shouldn't it? @T.J.Crowder
Isn't super(name) is doing the same thing as Thread(name)?

Comment: @AyushN: `new Thread(name)` does call the `Thread` constructor, but **not** on `this`, the object your constructor is in the process of initializing. It calls it on a new, unrelated instance instead. So no, as I said above, `super(name)` is completely different from `new Thread(name)`. **Unless** you want to create a **separate** thread, use `super`, not `new Thread`.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `new Thread(String name)` instead of `super(name)`, you are creating a new `Thread` object (which is not related to the `NewThread1` instance you just constructed), and pass to it the `name` parameter. Therefore your `NewThread1` instance has a default name in this case (since the compiler implicitly adds `super()` to call the `Thread` parameterless constructor.

```
NewThread1 (String name) {
    new Thread(name);
    System.out.println("child Thread:"+this);
}
```

is the same as

```
NewThread1 (String name) {
    super(); // name is not passed to the super class constructor
    new Thread(name);
    System.out.println("child Thread:"+this);
}
```

Comment: Thread(name) is also allocating a Thread object and so is super(name).
Now, super(name) is allocating to 'this' object but isn't it calling the same parent constructor Thread(name). so how does it allocates a Thread type object to NewThread1 type 'this' object? @Eran